# Массивы TASM/ASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Программа ищет максимально встречающиеся символы, и в массив с индексом равным коду символа записывает частоту встречаемости символа, но после второй записи(метка WRITE)(допустим строка aab), значение для символа 'a' изменяется в той ячейке на какое-то странное число(было 3, стало 768 и тд). Не знаю, как объяснить такое поведение массива. Прошу помочь.

```
STACKSG SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DW 128 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS
;---------------------
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
    LAST_ARR = 254
    MAX_LEN = 128
    STRING DB MAX_LEN, MAX_LEN DUP('$')
    EMPTY_MSG DB 0AH, 'Empty string!', 0AH, 24h
    FND_CHR DB 'Most common symbols: ', 24h
    ;MAX_FR DB 2 DUP(0)
    SYMBOLS DB 255 DUP(0)
    CNT DB 0
DATASG ENDS
;---------------------
CODESG SEGMENT PARA
    ASSUME DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG, ES:CODESG, SS:STACKSG
START:
    .386
    LEN EQU STRING + 1;длина строки
    BGN_STR EQU STRING + 2;адрес 1 символа


    PUSH DS
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    XOR AX, AX

    ;-----------------------
    ;ввод строки

    MOV AH, 10
    LEA DX, STRING
    INT 21h
    ;-----------------------
    XOR DX, DX

    MOV DL, 0AH
    MOV AH, 2 ;вывести на экран символ( перевод строки)
    INT 21h

    XOR DX, DX
    XOR AX, AX
    ;--------------------------

    MOV BX, 0
    LEA SI, BGN_STR
    MOV DI, SI
    MOV DX, SI; сохраним для внутренего

OUTER:
    ;PUSH SI
    MOV SI, DI; восстановим значение
    LODSB

    CMP AL, '$'
    CMP AL, 0Dh
    JE FIND_MAX

    MOV SI, DX
    ;DEC SI

    MOV AH, AL
    XOR AL, AL
    INNER:
        LODSB

        CMP AL, '$'
        CMP AL, 0Dh
        JE NEXT_ITER


        CMP AH, AL
        JNE INNER
        INC CX ;сколько раз встретили
        JMP INNER

NEXT_ITER:
    INC DI  
    MOV BL, AH; код символа
    CMP SYMBOLS[BX], CL ; CL-сколько раз встретился символ
    JL WRITE 
    JNL GO
WRITE:  
    MOV SYMBOLS[BX], CL ; в ячейку кода символа запищем встречаемость
    JMP GO

GO: 
    ;XOR BX, BX
    XOR CX, CX
    JMP OUTER

FIND_MAX:
    XOR BX, BX
    XOR AX, AX
    XOR CX, CX
    XOR SI, SI

    GET_MAX:
        CMP SI, LAST_ARR
        JA EXIT

        CMP SYMBOLS[SI], CL
        JG SAVE_SYMB
        INC SI
        JMP GET_MAX

SAVE_SYMB:
    MOV CL, SYMBOLS[SI]
    INC SI
    JMP GET_MAX



SHOW:
    XOR SI, SI
    SHOW_MAX:
        CMP SI, LAST_ARR
        JA EXIT 

        CMP SYMBOLS[SI], CL
        JE OUTPUT
        INC SI
        JMP SHOW_MAX
OUTPUT:
    MOV AH, 2
    MOV DL, byte ptr [SI]
    INT 21h
    INC SI
    JMP SHOW_MAX
EXIT:
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h

CODESG ENDS
END START
```

P.S. Я написал тест и заметил интересную вещь, что после выполнения кода ниже, в SYMBOLS[3]==1 и почему-то SYMBOLS[2]==256

```
STACKSG SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DW 128 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS
;---------------------
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
    SYMBOLS DB 255 DUP(0)
DATASG ENDS
;---------------------
CODESG SEGMENT PARA
    ASSUME DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG, ES:CODESG, SS:STACKSG
START:
    .386
    PUSH DS
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    XOR AX, AX
    ;--------------
    MOV BX, 3
    MOV byte ptr SYMBOLS[BX], 1

    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h

CODESG ENDS
END START
```

Comment: У вас массив DB, т.е. байтовый, а в байте физически не может быть значение 768. Чем вы его получили ? Еще странная конструкция `CMP AL, '$' /  CMP AL, 0Dh / JE NEXT_ITER` да еще в 2х местах. Первый CMP вообще не работает, ибо второй все его флаги затирает

Comment: @Mike CMP AL, '$' сравнение очередного символа с концом строки, CMP AL, 0Dh сравнение очередного символа с нажатием Enter, если одно что-то из этого, то идем дальше. Я заметил странную закономерность. При строке 'ab' у которой коды 61h, 62h в ячейку 61h записалось 1, потом в ячейку 62h записалась 1, но при этом в ячейке 61h значение увеличилось на 256(стало 101h) после записи встречаемости для символа 62h. Также пройдя вручную, я заметил, что почему-то в 60h ячейке лежало 256. Не знаю, как это объяснить, ведь массив инициализирован 0-ми

Comment: Я нашел закономерность, что при первой записи (допустим 'ba', в SYMBOLS[62h] запишется 1, в то время как в SYMBOLS[61h] пишется 100h, но почему так происходит, я не могу понять.P.S. При каждой записи, в ячейку на 1 меньше прибавляется 256 @Mike

Comment: один байт не может содержать 100h, это уже 9 бит, а байт у нас 8 битный. Ваше средство отладки просто показывает эту память словами, т.е. по два байта. И конечно, если в старшем байте 1, то при рассмотрении двух байт у вас будет 100h.

Comment: @Mike а почему при 1 команде пишется сразу в 2 ячейки

Comment: А что касается 2х cmp подряд, то они НЕ РАБОТАЮТ. Один cmp либо ставит, либо сбрасывает флаги, за счет которых работают команды Jxx. Так что Jxx должен быть после КАЖДОГО cmp. Предположим, первый cmp обнаружил совпадение. Он выставляет флаг в 1. Следующий за ним cmp не нашел совпадения и сбрасывает этот флаг в 0. т.е. то первое совпадение мы просто потеряли

Comment: Какая именно строка пишет сразу 2 ячейки ? Я вроде вижу, у вас везде однобайтовые регистры используются, так что оно не может писать 2 байта ну ни как.

Comment: @Mike про кмп буду знать, но что насчет второго кода, я все так и не понял, если я буду в цикле выводить, я получу не то, что нужно

Comment: по вашему второму примеру: SYMBOLS[2]==256 не может такого быть. максимальное значение, хранимое в одном байте 255. так что 256 в одном байте лежать не может. Значит ваше средство отладки не понимает что это байтовый массив и показывает его считая, что значения как минимум двубайтовые. Так что в памяти все правильно лежит, просто вы на это не стой стороны смотрите

Comment: @Mike предложите другое какое-то средство отладки? Мне просто эта штука портит весь вывод символов.

Comment: Так вы даже не сказали чем это смотрите. Оно наверняка показывает просто шестнадцетиричный дамп памяти, читайте его. И оно портить вывод символов не может. Вы же выводите всего 1 символ в итоге. Если вы получаете не то, что ожидалось, значит ошибка где то в другом месте. Для начала пройдите первую часть и посмотрите дамп вашего массива. Вот прямо на той строке aab вы в соответвующих двух байтах должны видеть 0x02 0x01. Если посмотрите это как на слово, то оно будет в десятичном = 257. Если это не так, значит проблема в первой части алгоритма. А если так, значит уже в поиске максимума

Comment: @Mike я только что узнал про дамп, извините, не знал

Answer (score 2):

Значение одного байта не может превышать 255. Вы смотрите двухбайтные значения в своем средстве отладки. Которые включают в себя сразу два элемента массива SYMBOLS.

Кроме того алгоритм подсчета символов очень сложный. Его корректность проверить тяжело. По факту вы берете очередной символ, пробегаете всю строку до конца, ищете такие же символы и считаете их. Значит для строки `aab` вы будете пересчитывать количество букв `a` два раза.
Гораздо проще один раз пробежать строку входных символов и увеличивать на 1 счетчик конкретного символа, примерно так:

```
MAX_LEN_B DB MAX_LEN
LEN       DB 0
STRING    MAX_LEN DUP(0)
SYMBOLS   DB 256 DUP(0)

    MOV AH, 10
    LEA DX, MAX_LEN_B
    INT 21h

    XOR CX, CX
    MOV CL, LEN               ; В CX реальная длина строки (для LOOP)
    LEA SI, STRING
    XOR BX, BX
COUNT:
    MOV BL, [SI]              ; Очередной символ
    INC SI
    INC BYTE PTR [SYMBOLS+BX] ; Увеличили кол-во такого символа
    LOOP COUNT

    MOV BX, 256               ; Последний элемент массива количеств + 1
    XOR CX, CX                ; CL будет макс кол-во, CH макс символ

FIND_MAX:
    DEC BX
    JZ  END_FIND              ; Нулевой символ проверять не будем, его сложно ввести
    MOV AL, [SYMBOLS+BX]
    CMP AL, CL
    JB  FIND_MAX              ; Текущий элемент меньше текущего максимума, след. символ
    MOV CH, BL                ; Запоминаем символ
    MOV CL, AL                ; И количество
    JMP FIND_MAX
END_FIND:
```

Comment: да, согласен, это более емко

Answer (score 0):

```
STACKSG SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DW 128 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS
;---------------------
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
    LAST_ARR = 254
    MAX_LEN = 128
    STRING DB MAX_LEN, MAX_LEN DUP('$')
    SYMBOLS DB 255 DUP(0)
DATASG ENDS
;---------------------
CODESG SEGMENT PARA
    ASSUME DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG, ES:CODESG, SS:STACKSG
START:
    .386
    LEN EQU STRING + 1;длина строки
    BGN_STR EQU STRING + 2;адрес 1 символа


    PUSH DS
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    XOR AX, AX

    ;-----------------------
    ;ввод строки

    MOV AH, 10
    LEA DX, STRING
    INT 21h
    ;-----------------------
    XOR DX, DX

    MOV DL, 0AH
    MOV AH, 2 ;вывести на экран символ( перевод строки)
    INT 21h

    XOR DX, DX
    XOR AX, AX
    ;--------------------------

    MOV BX, 0
    LEA SI, BGN_STR
    MOV DI, SI
    MOV DX, SI; сохраним для внутренего

OUTER:
    ;PUSH SI
    MOV SI, DI; восстановим значение
    LODSB

    CMP AL, '$'
    JE FIND_MAX
    CMP AL, 0Dh
    JE FIND_MAX

    MOV SI, DX
    ;DEC SI

    MOV AH, AL
    XOR AL, AL
    INNER:
        LODSB

        CMP AL, '$'
        JE NEXT_ITER
        CMP AL, 0Dh
        JE NEXT_ITER


        CMP AH, AL
        JNE INNER
        INC CX ;сколько раз встретили
        JMP INNER

NEXT_ITER:
    INC DI  
    MOV BL, AH; код символа
    CMP SYMBOLS[BX], CL ; CL-сколько раз встретился символ
    JL WRITE 
    JNL GO
WRITE:  
    MOV byte ptr SYMBOLS[BX], CL ; в ячейку кода символа запищем встречаемость
    JMP GO

GO: 
    ;XOR BX, BX
    XOR CX, CX
    JMP OUTER

FIND_MAX:
    XOR BX, BX
    XOR AX, AX
    XOR CX, CX
    XOR SI, SI

    GET_MAX:
        CMP SI, LAST_ARR
        JA SHOW

        CMP SYMBOLS[SI], CL
        JG SAVE_SYMB
        INC SI
        JMP GET_MAX

SAVE_SYMB:
    MOV CL, SYMBOLS[SI]
    INC SI
    JMP GET_MAX



SHOW:
    XOR SI, SI
    SHOW_MAX:
        CMP SI, LAST_ARR
        JA EXIT 

        CMP SYMBOLS[SI], CL
        JE OUTPUT
        INC SI
        JMP SHOW_MAX
OUTPUT:
    MOV AH, 2
    MOV DX, SI
    INT 21h

    MOV DL, 20h
    INT 21h

    XOR DX, DX

    INC SI
    JMP SHOW_MAX
EXIT:
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h

CODESG ENDS
END START
```